# cygwin git documentation

Tags: windows, git, cygwin, documentation

I just installed git using cygwin.
I then tried using `git help status` but I received the error `fatal: '/usr/share/doc/git-doc': not a documentation directory.` And indeed, there is no folder git-doc in `/usr/share`.

What do I need to do to get the documentation ? Did the installation go wrong, did I forget to install a package ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The Cygwin `git` package is indeed missing the HTML documentation.  This was probably missed because of a disparity in the upstream build system: while `make doc` creates both the man pages and HTML, `make install-doc` only installs the man pages; a separate `make install-html` is necessary.  I'll try to get this fixed in the Cygwin distribution.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [git wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Installation), you should do this:

> **Getting and installing documentation**
>
> You can find all the plain text documentation in the Git source tree's Documentation/ directory.
>
> In order to build the HTML version of the documentation you need to
>   have AsciiDoc version 7.0 or greater installed. Man pages also require
>   that xmlto is installed.
>
> To build and install documentation from the Git source code simply
>   run:
>
> ```
> $ make install-doc
> ```

Comment: I tried adding the asciidoc and xmlto packages (which I found in the repos), but the doc is still not there.
I don't understand what make install-doc means. Should I just type it in the terminal ? From which directory ? make is not installed, should I install it ?

Comment: I am not sure since I am not on windows/cygwin. I understand that you should open a terminal, `cd` into wherever you have downloaded the `git` sources and run the command `make install-doc` from the terminal.

Comment: Okay I think it works now (I manually downloaded the site). However I am redirected to a console-like browser (w3m.exe). I tried setting the value git config --global web.browser firefox, and even git config --global browser.firefox.path "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", but it doesn't work. What should I do to run the html with firefox ?

Comment: Umm, browse to the file using a file manager and double click?

Comment: Yes sure but I'm looking for a fix, not a work around :). I could also just google for git help status, but that's not what I'm looking for.